# i am unable to install whatsapp on my lumia 520, it just shows pending, what should i do?

Tags: whatsapp, lumia-520

From *yesterday*, I am trying to install whatsapp on my **wp(lumia 520)**.  I have checked my info about region, language,and other details, even my phone memory isn't over.  please help me.

Comment: Where you able to install other apps? Did you get any error code? Is the install location set to Internal memory?

Comment: Are you an insider?